# Apache Mass Virtual Host config issue

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, virtualhost

I have an Amazon ec2 instance with LAMP installed. I edited /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-deault.conf and added this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAlias *
        UseCanonicalName Off
        LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log vcommon
        VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/%0
</VirtualHost>

Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAlias *
        UseCanonicalName Off
        LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log vcommon
        VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/%0
</VirtualHost>
```

When I visit my domain names they point to the correct directory and it all works great except for one thing...when I visit the domains with www. it gives this error:

"Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server."

My directory structure is /var/www/vhosts/domain.com without the www. - could that be the problem and if so what can I do to fix that without adding both domain.com and www.domain.com directories?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this `VirtualDocumentRoot`, instead:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/%-2.0.%-1.0"
```

This will make all subdomains (including `www.example.com`) point to `/var/www/vhosts/example.com`, too.

BTW, if this is your only/first virtual host (on each port), you shouldn't need `ServerAlias *` at all; if no other matching virtualhost is found, the default virtualhost gets used anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration has

```
UseCanonicalName Off
```

CannonicalName is a type of DNS entry.

servername.com is a DNS type A

www.servername.com is a DNS type CNAME, redirecting to DNS type a servername.com

In the default, UseCanonicalName is disabled, remove the lines from configuration file and reload/restart the apache service with

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

---

Its recommended you configure ServerName and ServerAlias, for return 200 code and web page only if DNS match.

ServerName servername.com

ServerAlias www.servername.com ww2.servername.com

---

You line Listen 443 is not necessary in this configuration file, place in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: I removed UseCanonicalName Off from both entries and restarted apache. I'm still getting a 404 Not found. You also mentioned returning only if DNS matched, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Remove the line "ServerAlias *" and add "ServerName youdns.com" and "ServerAlias www.youdns.com" in another line.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean I need a new vhost entry for each domain?